# Salt stack: Create user and group with same name

Tags: python, salt-stack

I am trying to create a user and a group on multiple linux servers with the same name, nagios.

I have this block of code:

```
nagios:
  group:
    - present
  user:
    - present
    - fullname: Nagios System Monitoring
    - shell: /bin/bash
    - home: /opt/nagios
```

The group gets created properly, but the user does not and I can't get salt to tell me why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.user.html

```
user.present:
  - gid_from_name
    If True, the default group id will be set to the 
    id of the group with the same name as the user, Default is False.
```

Also, generally, you can get better debug output by ssh'ing into the target minion and running the state via `salt-call` with or without `-l debug`.